# Generate a dynamic ul li List from DB

Tags: php

I don't arrived to create a dynamic Menu from a DB

```
><ul class="sub">
                        <li class='hidden'>id</li><li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                        <li class='hidden'>id</li><li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                        <li class='hidden'>id</li><li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                        <li class='hidden'>id</li><li><a href="#">d</a></li>
                        <li class='hidden'>id</li><li><a href="#">e</a></li>
 </ul>
>
```

I have this array from a DB

> Array (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [id_zub] => 1
>               [name] => a
>           )
>
> ```
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [id_zub] => 2
>         [name] => b
>     )
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         [id_zub] => 3
>         [name] => c
>     )
> [3] => Array
>     (
>         [id_zub] => 4
>         [name] => b
>     )
> [4] => Array
>     (
>         [id_zub] => 5
>         [name] => b
>     )
> ```
>
> )

i have this Funktion, How can i insert the Tag ,

> function ulLiList($array){
>
> ```
> foreach($array as $key=> $value){
>
>     if(is_array($value)){
>         $this->array_flattern($value);
>     }
>     else{
>         $this->menu .= '<li>'.$key.'</li><li>'.$value.'</li>';
>     }
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may test this function to generate list dynamically.

```
function createList($lists){
$html_list = "<ul>";
foreach($lists as $list){
 $html_list .= '<li class="hidden">'. $list['id_zub'] .'</li><li><a href="#">'. $list['name'] . '</a></li>';
}
$html_list .= "</ul>";

return $html_list;
}
```

Where $lists =

```
 Array ( 

    [0] => Array ( 
            [id_zub] => 1 
            [name] =>'a' 
    )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_zub] => 2
            [name] => 'b'
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_zub] => 3
            [name] => 'c'
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_zub] => 4
            [name] => 'd'
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id_zub] => 5
            [name] => 'e'
        )

    )
```